# Integrate Swagger 0.3.x with Django and Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger

Working on rather old project running `Django 1.6` there's a need to integrate Swagger to describe REST endpoints.

I've installed compatible version of `Django Rest Framework` (3.2.5) and `Django Rest Swagger` (0.3.0), then imported both into `INSTALLED APPS` and included `DRF-Swagger's` urls in my url scheme:

```
...    
url(r'^api/v1/$', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls')),
...
```

[image]
When I go to this URL I see that Swagger is working, but I can't understand what should I do next to make it work with my endpoints and show information about them? Should I add something to `SWAGGER_SETTINGS` to be able to read `YAML` insertions from methods?

Comment: open up browser console, you may have some errors.

Comment: @JibinMathews , you are right, it says "Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:8000/api/v1/api-docs/" but I don't understand where should I put swagger description for this specific endpoint or for all of them. I've read how it's done in Django-Swagger v2.0 but it's different than in 0.3.x

Comment: can you update url as follows url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls')),

Comment: @JibinMathews I don't receive errors anymore, console says "Loaded SwaggerUI", what are my next steps?

Comment: 1.6 is not supported since April 2015 and is not receiving security fixes. Scary!

Comment: @Kos, unfortunately there's nothing I can do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to configure this version of `swagger` to work with `DRF` is first to install both packages compatible with `Django 1.6`:

```
pip install djangorestframework==3.2.5
pip install django-rest-swagger==0.3.0
```

Then you should add both to installed apps in `project settings`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework_swagger',
)
```

Optionally you can add `SWAGGER_SETTINGS` to `project settings`, but it's not mandatory, here's a link to [SWAGGER_SETTINGS](http://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/stable-0.3.x/settings.html).

Then you should add this pattern to your urls:

```
url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls'))
```

you can make it extend existing path, for example:

```
url(r'^<your root path>/docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls'))
```

but the key is that this url should end with exactly `docs/` to be able to access `swagger`. At this point if everything is done correctly you should be able to access Swagger at:

`<your root path>/docs/`

Last thing you need to do is import and decorate your endpoint `View` with api_view decorator:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
...

@api_view(["GET"]) 
def my_api_view(request, parameter_a, parameter_b):
"""
Endpoint returns list of open orders
---
parameters:
    - name: parameter_a
      description: Description for parameter a
      required: true
      paramType: path
    - name: parameter_b
      description: Description for parameter b
      required: true
      paramType: path
"""

...rest of View...
```

This will tell Swagger that this endpoint is related to `DRF` and has description to be displayed at `<your root path>/docs/`